# How to change all occurrence of DD/MM/YYYY in a string to MM/DD/YYYY format in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

How to change all occurrence of DD/MM/YYYY in a string to MM/DD/YYYY format.

Input string: *I graduated on 09/08/2016 and joined PHD on 01/07/2017 then since 25/10/2011 I works on*

to

Output string: *I graduated on 08/09/2016 and joined PHD on 07/01/2017 then since 10/25/2011 I works on*

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) to find and replace all date occurrences:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'I graduated on 09/08/2016 and joined PHD on 01/07/2017 then since 25/10/2011 I works on'
>>> re.sub(r'(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{4})', r'\2/\1/\3', s)
'I graduated on 08/09/2016 and joined PHD on 07/01/2017 then since 10/25/2011 I works on'
```

Above will capture all occurrences of pattern `dd/dd/dddd` where `d` is a digit to a three different groups. Then it will just output a string where first and second group have been swapped.

Comment: Ah, I like yours much better. Wasn't aware you could so easily refer to capturing groups. Glad to learn something. :) Still posting my solution as I'd already been working on it for a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with the re module and a replacement function.

```
import re

# make the re pattern object
# it looks for the following pattern: 2 digits / 2 digits / 4 digits
date_pattern = re.compile(r'\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}')

# make the replacement function to be called to replace matches
# takes the match object, splits the date up and swaps the first two elements
def swap_date_arrangement(date_string):
    return_string = date_string.group(0).split('/')
    return_string[0], return_string[1] = return_string[1], return_string[0]
    return '/'.join(return_string)

# test the solution...
input_string = "I graduated on 09/08/2016 and joined PHD on 01/07/2017 then since 25/10/2011 I work on..."

# assign the new string
replaced_string = re.sub(date_pattern, swap_date_arrangement, input_string)

print replaced_string
```